# Is there anything I won't be able to do once the water level drops?

Tags: god-of-war-2018

In God of War, the Lake of the Nine has a lot to explore. However there are some things that are inaccessible, and appears that they are only more inaccessible once the water level drops.

One such thing I came across was one of the Eyes of Odin, perched on the other end of a shipwreck. I was within range the first time, but there was no place close enough to dock. Now that the water level has dropped, the entire shipwreck is out of range.

So, is there anything that I am going to miss after I drop the water level?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No you can't miss anything as the water drops.

All the areas that were originally accessed from docks at the higher water level are still accessible from the lower areas through various paths and climbing sections although you may need some specific skills, such as removing the thorny branches, or solve some of the exploding rock puzzles to get there.

Source: I have played the game and obtained 100% completion and I consulted various guides to collect everything. All the collectables can still be obtained after and the water drops and, minor spoiler:

> in the post game after the main quest is complete.

Comment: that spoiler is... probably one of the most non-spoiler spoiler I've read.

Comment: Rightfully tagged as a spoiler as it directly relates to how the game ends...